# Nodejs express session - not load session for static content?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using express session like this inside my server.js and inside the app.configuire() block.

I want to use session only if there's some api calls but not in those static content loading as it seems it will extend session which I don't want.

So is there a way to specific not to use session for those static content?

```
app.use(express.session({ secret: sessionVal }));
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Express.js Documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html)

```
app.use([path,] function [, function...])
```

You have to specify path (optional) as a first parameter, when using app.use()
for example:

```
app.use('/api', express.session({ secret: sessionVal }))
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the info. If I've another path example like /member then how can I add it with api?

Comment: Or if there is a way to specify not to have that line when loading static file like *.js, *.html, *.jpg, *.css that maybe even better so next time I need another path that needs to load session then I don't have to modify server.js?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My problem was that I was calling the

```
app.use(express.static("views"))
```

before my session middleware. Your session middleware should be called first, then the Static Content middleware.